# Checking a device can receive SMS or not

Tags: android, sms

There're some SIM card without phone number but you can use it to access internet via the cellular network. For that kind of SIM card, I think they are not able to receive SMS as they don't have phone number.

I'm in trouble checking a phone can receive SMS or not. Do you have some insight for me?

Comment: what is the purpose of your development ?

Comment: I think no such feature in android. But you say what is your actual requirement.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. In my case, I have a system to send SMS to device for verification. If the device can't receive SMS, i will probably skip that part of verification. So I have to check such condition.

Answer (score 1):

You can use TelephonyManager, Sim card should be one of these status.

```
TelephonyManager telMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
int simState = telMgr.getSimState();
        switch (simState) {
            case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_ABSENT:
                // do something
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_NETWORK_LOCKED:
                // do something
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_PIN_REQUIRED:
                // do something
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_PUK_REQUIRED:
                // do something
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_READY:
                // do something
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_UNKNOWN:
                // do something
                break;
        }
```

Comment: I think your code can check whether Sim card is installed but not whether that SIM can receive SMS.

Comment: I think  case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_NETWORK_LOCKED: gives whether it can receive SMS and make calls.

Comment: Just tried, my phone report TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_READY in normal mode, TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_UNKNOWN in airplane mode. I think it's not going to enter TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_NETWORK_LOCKED.

Comment: send your sim state to log then you can get your current simstate. So you can work according to it.

Comment: That's the best method would be but unfortunately I don't have different types of Sim cards right now.